# selenium click() method doesn't work after perfectly working a couple of hours before

Tags: python, selenium, click

I'm using selenium to like automatically some pictures. So the script searches for a word, clicks on the first picture, locates the like button then clicks on it.
The click button works to click on the picture but not to like it... I didn't change the identifier, so the class name is perfectly fine. I don't where the problem could come.

Here's my code :
'''

```
class Interact(Browser):

    #click on the firt picture in the page
    def firstpic_click(self):
        time.sleep(2)
        first = self.browser.find_element_by_class_name("kIKUG")
        first.click()

    #likes curent picture
    def like_pic(self):
        time.sleep(2)
        like = self.browser.find_element_by_class_name("fr66n")
        soup = bs(like.get_attribute('innerHTML'),'html.parser')
        if (soup.find('svg')['aria-label'] == 'Like'):
            like.click()


        time.sleep(2)

    #returns and clicks on next picture if any
    def next_picture(self):
        time.sleep(2)
        try:
    #       nex = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//svg[@aria-label="Next"]')
            next = self.browser.find_elements_by_class_name("wpO6b  ")
            soups = [bs(nextt.get_attribute('innerHTML'),'html.parser') for nextt in next]
            for i in range(len(soups)):
                #print(soups[i])
                if (soups[i].find('svg')['aria-label'] == 'Next'):
                    next[i].click()
                    return next[i]
            #nex = self.browser.find_element_by_xpath('//button[@class="wpO6b  "]')
            #time.sleep(1)
            #return nex
        except selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException:
            return 0

    #liking all the next pictures if any
    def continue_liking(self):
        while(True):
            next_el = self.next_picture()
            if next_el != False:
                self.like_pic()
                time.sleep(2)
                next_el.click()
                time.sleep(2)
            else:
                print("not found")
                break

    def word_search(self, search=1):
        # word = input("what?")
        word = "lol"
        #search is the method of search

        #looking for word in search box
        if search == 0:
            search_box = self.browser.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@aria-label='Search Input']")
            search_box.send_keys("#"+word)
            time.sleep(2)
            #search_box.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
            #search_box.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
            search_box.submit()
            time.sleep(5)
        #type the website directly
        if search == 1:
            self.browser.get("https://www.instagram.com/explore/tags/" + word)

def liking_pictures(browser0):
    browser0.implicitly_wait(5)

    browser = Interact(browser0)
    browser.word_search()
    browser.firstpic_click()

    browser.like_pic()
    browser.next_picture()
    browser.continue_liking()
    time.sleep(10)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    with browse() as browser0:
        #unsubscribing(browser0)
        liking_pictures(browser0)
```

'''
Thank you

Comment: Any errors in console ?

Comment: did you run in console/terminal to see errors? Don't expect that we will run it to get error. Besides code may work corectly on our computers.

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information.

Comment: you could put code with `imports` - so we could simply copy code to test it and see problem in browser.